# Drupal VIEWS Price Filter

Tags: drupal, filter

I have a VIEWS page set up to display various products and would like to be able to filter them by price range.  I've read that "Contextual Filters" is the right way to go about this but when I add a filter, the field (price) isn't listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter doesn't need to be a contextual filter (those are used to fetch a parameter from e.g the url of your page). If you just need to filter your products by price just set a regular filter on the price field. If you want to define a range, set two filters : price > min and price < max. If you need to expose it to users, you have to set ajax on (advanced section), and you can use [Better Exposed Filter](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) to get a nice slider (with jQuery Slider).

Comment: I was able to use "Grouped Filters".